# Backup and restore AWS load balancers

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, elastic-load-balancer

We have several AWS test environments with LoadBalancers. This cost a lot of money as LoadBalancers can not be turned off. I therefor tries to create a script to Back them of and restore them.
I tryed this:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name testLB --output json > .\testLB.json
```

This gives a json file but when i try create a new form that file i though I'd just

```
aws elb create-load-balancer  --cli-input-json file://testLB.json
```

but then i get a long error like

```
C:\code\AWS-Scripts\LoadbalancerScript [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 | +6 ~1 -0 !]> aws elb create-load-balancer  --cli-input-json file://test3.json
```

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received:  ■{

```
     " L o a d B a l a n c e r D e s c r i p t i o n s " :   [

             {

                     " S u b n e t s " :   [

                             " s u b n e t - 1 2 3 4 5 a b c "

                     ] ,

                     " C a n o n i c a l H o s t e d Z o n e N a m e I D " :   " 1 2 3 4 5 a b c d e f g h 6 " ,
```

and the wired spacing diapers if i change the file from UCS-2-LE BOM to UTF 8 bit it still does not parse:

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: test3.json

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Tryed to use  --generate-cli-skeleton and then

```
aws elb create-load-balancer --cli-input-json file://C:\code\AWS-Scripts     \LoadbalancerScript\lbSkeleton.json

But that returned:

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: {
"LoadBalancerName": "testBalancer",
"Listeners": [
    {
        "InstancePort": 8003,
        "LoadBalancerPort": 8003,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP"
    },
],
"AvailabilityZones": [
    "eu-central-1b"
],
"Subnets": [
    "subnet-123123123"
],
"SecurityGroups": [
    "sg-123123",
    "sg-123123"
],
"Scheme": "",
"Tags": [
    {
        "Key": "Environment",
        "Value": "123123"
    }
]
```

}

Plz help

Comment: This is literally what [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) or [Hashicorp terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) are intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at using CloudFormation template to launch and turn off any AWS Resources. [Cloudformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) is helpful for creating templates for existing resources.

---

If you still need to use the CLI, you can generate CLI Skeleton JSON that outlines all of the parameters that can be specified for the operation. you can then fill up the values and then create the load balancers

`aws elb create-load-balancer --generate-cli-skeleton`

```
{
    "LoadBalancerName": "",
    "Listeners": [
        {
            "Protocol": "",
            "LoadBalancerPort": 0,
            "InstanceProtocol": "",
            "InstancePort": 0,
            "SSLCertificateId": ""
        }
    ],
    "AvailabilityZones": [
        ""
    ],
    "Subnets": [
        ""
    ],
    "SecurityGroups": [
        ""
    ],
    "Scheme": "",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "",
            "Value": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: when I fill this out and try:
aws elb create-load-balancer  --cli-input-json file://C:\code\AWS-Scripts\LoadbalancerScript\lbSkeleton.json
 Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON 
I get
object could be decoded

Comment: post your json please

Comment: It's posted after the updated section in the question

Comment: There is an extra comma at line 8, here is corrected json  https://pastebin.com/T8tE5qif